# CSS keyframe-mobile starts at 100% before animating

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have the css class and keyframes below to animate an image fading in and sliding in from the left.

The transition works just fine on desktop however on mobile device, the transition acts like it is complete displaying the 100% keyframe first, then the transition begins at 0% and performs the animation like you would expect.

I tried adding the 0% style to the original class to start it out at the correct position before the animation begins however this didn't work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```css
.slideLeft {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: visible;
}


@keyframes slideInLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: visible;

    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://content.mycutegraphics.com/graphics/food/whole-pizza.png" class="slideLeft"/>
```

Comment: Try remove the `visibility: visible;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 visibility: visible;
}


@keyframes slideInLeft {
    9% {
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;

    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
       
    }
}
```

```html
<img height="70" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/828213014599839749/VGv8LT6T.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, it looks like the issue was not entirely css related.  This was a project that I was brought into after the pages were built, I found that there was a javascript that was appending a .start class to the item when it was scrolled into view which would trigger the transition.  The fix was my original thought, adding the 0% keyframe values to the class so they start out in the correct position before the transition starts.  I just had to track down all of the classes that had a .start transition associated and add in the keyframe values.

Comment: Then delete the question, as it has no value for future users